# QuickFix/N Logout other connections when new session is logged in

Tags: c#, quickfix, quickfixn

Using QuickFIX/n I want to disconnect other connections when the session is Logged in. For example the client is logged in, but for the same SenderCompId new Logon on another connection is received, the first session should be disconnected instead of the new Logon be silently blocked.

Any ideas on how to configure/code that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for: I doubt that this can be configured since an incoming session should be disconnected if there already was an established connection with the same CompIDs.

> If, during a logon, one receives a second connection attempt while a
> valid FIX session is already underway for that same SenderCompID(49),
> the session acceptor should immediately terminate the second
> connection attempt and not send a Logout(35=5) message.

Source: https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/fix-session-layer-online/#fix-connection-termination
(search for "When to terminate a FIX connection")